# Is there a better query to achieve the same results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I wrote a query like this in MySQL.

```
select ass.Name, lbnm.ProductName, COUNT(*) as lb_count
from
(
select lbid from
lockbox.Ac2018 ac
where ac.AccessType not in ('Gen') AND ac.UTCAccessedDT > '2018-10-10 00:00:00'
UNION
select lbid from
lockbox.Ac2019 ac
where ac.AccessType not in ('Gen') AND ac.UTCAccessedDT > '2019-10-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY lbid
) p
join
lockbox.LBMFG mfg
on p.LBID = mfg.LBID
join lockbox.LockBox lb
on mfg.LBID = lb.LBID
join lockbox.Ass ass
on ass.AssocID = lb.AssocID
JOIN lockbox.LBNames lbnm
ON lbnm.TopAssembly = mfg.TopAssembly
GROUP BY ass.Name, lbnm.ProductName
```

Although it's working fine but I am thinking of a better way of doing this especially the sub-query part (can it be written differently to improve the speed). Thanks for the help.

Comment: please provide table structure and expected results

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576) A [mcve] includes the table structures, sample data and the desired output as well as your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan.

Given that the inline view returns distinct values of `lbid`,  we could rewrite that as correlated subquery to check for existence of a matching row.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ass.name
     , lbnm.productname
     , COUNT(*)          AS lb_count
 FROM lockbox.Ass ass

 JOIN lockbox.LockBox lb
   ON lb.assoc = ass.associd

 JOIN lockbox.LBMFG mfg
   ON mfg.lbid = lb.lbid

 JOIN lockbox.LBNames lbnm
   ON lbnm.topassembly = mfg.topassembly

WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM lockbox.Ac2018 ac18
                WHERE ac18.accesstype     NOT IN ('Gen')
                  AND ac18.utcaccesseddt  > '2018-10-10 00:00:00'
                  AND ac18.lbid           = mfg.lbid
             )
   OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM lockbox.Ac2019 ac19
                WHERE ac19.accesstype      NOT IN ('Gen')
                  AND ac19.utcaccesseddt   > '2019-10-01 00:00:00'
                  AND ac19.lbid            = mfg.lbid
             )
GROUP
   BY ass.name
    , lbnm.productname
```

There is no guarantee this will be more efficient or faster; but it looks like the correlated subqueries can make advantageous use of indexes on Ac2018 and Ac2019, leading columns

```
  ... (lbid, utcaccesseddt, ... )
```

If the index also contains `accesstype` column, it would be a covering index, i.e. subquery satisfied entirely from index pages without lookup to pages in underlying table i.e. we expect `EXPLAIN` output to show "Using index" in the Extra column

```
  ... (lbid, utcaccesseddt, ... , accesstype  )
```

Again, use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan, and verify suitable indexes are available and being used.

NOTE:  I don't see any way to get around the "Using filesort" operation for the `GROUP BY`.  For a large set, that's likely the "big rock" in terms of performance ...

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` is redundant, so you can just use:

```
from (select lbid
      from lockbox.Ac2018 ac
      where ac.AccessType not in ('Gen') and ac.UTCAccessedDT > '2018-10-10'
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select lbid
      from lockbox.Ac2019 ac
      where ac.AccessType not in ('Gen') and ac.UTCAccessedDT > '2019-10-01'
     ) p
```

Other than that, I don't think there is much more that can be done.